# Use the same PartitionKey and RowKey

Tags: azure, primary-key, azure-table-storage

I know it is working but I will like to know it this is a good practice of having the same string as PartitionKey and RowKey?

Thi scenario is for one single table where all items are unique, `Customer` table where every row has info about one single customer.

What I mean is that for example I will get this unique customer ID and I want to use it to get the record by PartitionKey + RowKey so the return will be fast and one single item.

What do you think?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will certainly make your customer look up quick.  The RowKey can be an empty string so you technically don't have to make PartitionKey and Rowkey match if you will have a unique partition for every customer.

A couple of things to note here:

- You're giving up adding customers in batch or updating them in batch.  Since only entities in the same partition can be worked with in batch, if you have a single entity partition scheme there will be no batches.  Given what you've outlined above I don't think this will bother you.
- Any sort of range query against the partitionKey, such as all customers between 1 and 200, will end up possibly spanning multiple partition servers making this a very inefficient query.  Again, if you are only going to look a customer up one at a time and never in groups you should be fine.  Might want to think about that scenario where you have to go add a property to EVERY customer in your system and how you would handle that if it became necessary (a multi-threaded updater with a set of known customer IDs may be just fine, but you should at least think about it).
- Try avoid an append only pattern.  Meaning if your customer IDs are consecutive then as you add them they will initially be on the same partition server.  Only after a segment of them get hot will they be moved off to another server.  It's better to do a hash of the ID and use that as the PartitionKey which will cause them to be scattered more across multiple partition servers if you start really hammering on them.  You may not actually see that depending on your load.

Check out the [How to get most out of Windows Azure Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsazurestorage/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables) article on choosing partition keys.  You'll see most of what I said here is there as well (one of the places I learned it from) plus more.

Comment: If I understood your point right, it will be better then to have a common ID (guid for example) as a partition key and then the row key will contain my unique customer ID and in this case I will still be able to get the customer by partionkey + rowkey but also make use of batches?

Comment: I would not recommend keeping just one PartitionKey (e.g. `Users`) as that would defeat the whole purpose of partitioning. Assuming you have 100000 users and you set PartitionKey as `Users` and RowKey as unique id. When you search for users, table service will have to scan through those 100000 records to find matching user id. In this case you would be better off keeping unique id as the PartitionKey. HTH.

Comment: No, I was only saying that you should be aware that batching only works with entities from the same partition. As Gaurav indicated if you put everything in the same partition you will have a drastic impact on the scalability of your system for the worse.  What you are suggesting with a single customer per partition key is viable as long as you will always know the partition key.

Comment: I agree it would be best to use the partition key to group your customers into sets. You should not have only one customer per partition because that will prevent you from doing batch operations, which are more efficient. (And you should not have just one partition to hold all customers either because that would limit your scalability to around 2000 transactions per second.) Here's an article with more information about how partition keys and row keys work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796231.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using a consistent string ID, "0" as your RowKey has the same uniqueness outcome as double PK. PK+0 = PK+PK.

A practical solution is considering the most common query process. You might use the zip/pocode within the PartitionKey -- and then the customer GUID in the RowKey. If your customer base is evenly spread over the country. PartitionKey doesn't necessitate PrimaryKey...